# Using Oracle database with CakePHP 2.0

Tags: oracle, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1, cakephp-2.2

I have noticed there's no datasource for Oracle in CakePHP 2.0 for the moment, although it seems they are working on in it now: http://ask.cakephp.org/questions/view/any_news_about_oracle_datasource_with_cakephp_2_0

There are some people explaining how to use an Oracle DB adapting some code from CakePHP 1.3:
http://www.hassanbakar.com/2012/01/09/using-oracle-in-cakephp-2-0/
http://liamgraham.wordpress.com/2007/04/19/using-oracle-with-cakephp-15-minute-blog-tutorial/

But I'm not sure that's the correct way. If it was so simple, they would have released the feature already for CakePHP 2.X...

Would I have any trouble using that *"cheat"*?

I want to connect CakePHP with PL/SQL procedures and a desktop application and they are working over Oracle. I can not change that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After asking some CakePHP developers I came out with the conclusion that it is not possible to use an Oracle Database with CakePHP 2.3 if you want to make a proper use of CakePHP Models and their query syntax. There's no yet available any driver for Oracle in CakePHP which is completely functional.

Therefore, the solution I found was to use the [OCI8 Functions](http://php.net/manual/en//function.oci-parse.php) of PHP.

Like this i could use `oci_parse` to directly query against the DB or rather call a PL-SQL procedure which is what I finally decided to do. (because of the sql functions complexity and the division of task inside my work group)

Now, I can not make use of many of the advantages of using CakePHP models, but It was the only way.

Answer (score 3):

There is a new [CakePHP 3 Driver for Oracle Database](https://github.com/CakeDC/cakephp-oracle-driver) released (MIT) and working with Oracle 11g and Oracle 12c databases. Some features:

- Triggers
- Sequences
- Cursors
- Stored procedures
- Packages
- All the basic CRUD features to allow select/insert/update/delete rows.
- CakePHP Pagination
- CakePHP Bake code generation

Check the [Documentation here](https://github.com/CakeDC/cakephp-oracle-driver/blob/master/docs/Home.md), and the [release announcement here](http://www.cakedc.com/yevgeny_tomenko/2016/03/10/cakephp_3_driver_for_oracle_database).