# Use Cakephp 2.4.4 with oracle?

Tags: cakephp

Can I use CakePHP 2.4.4 with Oracle database? I looked in 
Model/Datasource/Database/ there only seems to be support for Mysql, 
Postgres, Sqlite, Sqlserver. But working with an existing Oracle 
database is my job's requirement. I would be thankful for any tips. 
Thank you.

Comment: Check out answer for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376743/using-oracle-dabase-with-cakephp-2-0

Answer (score 0):

No it's not possible. Well, not if you want to use some official driver. You can find a driver here : http://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/40032847
You will probably have to make some modifications to this driver to be able to make more complex queries.

In your config file, you will need to add your database connection information this way :

```
class DATABASE_CONFIG {
public $default = array(
        'datasource' => 'Database/Oracle',
        'driver' => 'oracle',
        'persistent' => false,
        'host' => 'hostname',
        'login' => 'username',
        'password' => 'yourpassword',
        'database' => '(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = hostname)(PORT = 1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=mysid)))',
    'prefix' => '',
);
```

Also it does not support using a different schema than the one you log in with so you need to create a trigger on your db to switch automatically to the schema you want to work with on login.

I hope this helps in getting you started.

I would suggest you use Zend instead of Cakephp.

Also see this post :
[Using Oracle database with CakePHP 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376743/using-oracle-database-with-cakephp-2-0)