# CakePHP track consuming resources query

Tags: sql, cakephp, logging, cakephp-2.5, cakephp-2.x

I need to track where in my CakePHP 2.5.2 app this query is being executed (as reported by DebugKit):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM sometable WHERE status = 1
```

I have found a model where the table is referenced, and maybe it is referenced in other places.

Is there a better way other than just looking for models or running every possible PHP script to find where this query came from in my CakePHP app?

Comment: This is probably a query cakephp runs internally. Perhaps you have a query similar to this without the count thing.

Comment: Must be some internal query, all the models and controllers i see does not trigger this query. I would like to discover where it happens and  change to a more performant query .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend the `Mysql` class and override `logQuery()` so that it logs every request with the logging mechanism of your choice.

Example:

1. Create the file `/app/Model/Datasource/MysqlLog.php` and add the following:

   ```
   App::uses('Mysql', 'Model/Datasource/Database');

   class MysqlLog extends Mysql {    

       function logQuery($sql, $params = []) {
           parent::logQuery($sql);
           Debugger::log("sql[{$this->_queriesCnt}]: $sql");
       }
   }
   ```
2. Instruct CakePHP to use the new class by modifying your `/app/Config/database.php`:

   ```
   public $default = array(
       'datasource' => 'Database/MysqlLog',
       'persistent' => true,
       'host' => 'localhost',
       'login' => 'my_login',
       'password' => 'my_pass',
       'database' => 'my_db',
   );
   ```

Requests will be logged to `/app/tmp/logs/debug.log`.

Based on the post [Logging sql queries into file in CakePHP 2](http://volod-0x16.livejournal.com/10923.html) by Vladimir Bilyov.

Comment: Is there any property i can set into the model so this count will use just one field to perform better ?

Comment: First of all you need to find out where it's coming from. If it has to do with pagination, perhaps [this](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/pagination.html#custom-query-pagination) helps. However, `count(*)` should be quicker than `count(field)`. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3003477/3144159).

Comment: It should be possible, if you apply the same principle. But I'm not sure that Oracle is fully supported by CakePHP. See this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376743/using-oracle-database-with-cakephp-2-0